# Error during JAXWS call with basic authentication

Tags: java, web-services, soap, cxf

i am facing this error stack while invoking a remote method located on a remote jbods server 
the probleam apear when i make the second call of a method located on a diffrent wsdl 
it seem that the server reject my request with an http response 401 not authorized ,
when i cal the methos properly with an other java client, it works correctly

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException: Failed to create service.
at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.<init>(ServiceImpl.java:150)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.spi.ProviderImpl.createServiceDelegate(ProviderImpl.java:65)
at javax.xml.ws.Service.<init>(Service.java:77)
at com.alpha_eng.ws.cloudupdate.LdapCloudUpdateWSImplService.<init>(LdapCloudUpdateWSImplService.java:43)
at com.alpha_eng.ws.tools.CommunicationCloudUpdate.getCloudUpdateport(CommunicationCloudUpdate.java:41)
at com.alpha_eng.cloudupdate.ChangerPassword.ModifierPassword(ChangerPassword.java:22)
at com.alpha_eng.ldapcloud.MajInfosClient.main(MajInfosClient.java:63)
Caused by: org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException:  Failed to create service.
at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLServiceFactory.<init> (WSDLServiceFactory.java:93)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.initializePorts(ServiceImpl.java:205)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.<init>(ServiceImpl.java:148)
... 6 more
Caused by: javax.wsdl.WSDLException: WSDLException:  faultCode=PARSER_ERROR: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxParsingException: Unexpected    close tag </body>; expected </HR>.
at [row,col,system-id]:   [1,1096,"https://omcr/ldapWS/services/ldapCloudUpdate?wsdl"]
at     org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLManagerImpl.loadDefinition(WSDLManagerImpl.java:226)
at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLManagerImpl.getDefinition(WSDLManagerImpl.java:179)
at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLServiceFactory.<init>(WSDLServiceFactory.java:91)
... 8 more
Caused by: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxParsingException: Unexpected close tag </body>; expected </HR>.
at [row,col,system-id]: [1,1096,"https://omcr/ldapWS/services/ldapCloudUpdate?wsdl"]
at com.ctc
```

Answer (score 0):

"401 not authorized" means you are not sending the correct username/password to the service. Check the security header in the request you are sending and compare it against the request from the java client that worked. I would be surprised if you are getting 401 when authentication details are correct.

Comment: i am not able to track the error code , may it is not "401"  but the reponse is html , it can not be the web service response , i supposed the the server reject my request so as in the browser it return the 401 error rendred in a html page so teh java client can't parse it ;

Comment: the second call is failling from the first step LdapTestUpdateWSImplService ss = new LdapTestUpdateWSImplService(CloudUpdate_WSDL_LOCATION,SERVICE_CloudUpdate);

Comment: There is a parse error in the stack trace you pasted. You calling the webservice from a different app hosted on a different server. Do I understand this correctly? If thats the case, two scenarios could cause this error: (1) Access is denied to wsdl due to folder permissions or the user id sending GET request for WSDL (2) WSDL was modified by the owner and there is an error in the new WSDL causing parse failure

Comment: i am ussing a lass to set credential befor i make call ,

Comment: i have notice that the bloc of teh authetification is not used for the second call   i am ussing ==>  Authenticator myAuthc = new Authenticator() 
      {
         
         protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication()
         {System.out.println("passAuth");
             return new PasswordAuthentication("*******", "*******$".toCharArray());
         }
      };
  
     Authenticator.setDefault(myAuthc);